# Log build file size using Jenkins and display results

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

This is a broad question, so any answers are deeply appreciated. I need to continually log the size of several build files (in this case some CSS and JS files), preserve this log and ideally show it as a dashboard in Jenkins.

I know that I can setup a cron job and execute a bash script to grab the files and log their size, but I'm not sure where this file would live and how to display it. Ideally the result would be a dashboard plot or bar graph over time.

Thanks.

P.S. I'm open to other logging suggestions, but Jenkins seems like the appropriate system to do this in.

Answer (score 1):

Update: this isn't perfect but it works. Google Spreadsheets has a simple API for posting data, so this can work as an endpoint for any script you want to write that logs your data.

It's not a Jenkins solution, but gets the job done.

In my search leading up to this, I did come across [JMeter](http://ibalosh.tumblr.com/post/35475979058/running-jmeter-tests-with-jenkins), and the [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) for Jenkins, which were contenders for a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for coming back with a useful response!